# Access mdb file content from .net when mdb file has password

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, ado.net, database-connection

I am creating a window application in C# and was thinking of setting up a password on mdb file of MS-Access so that no one can open that file other than my window application or who so ever knows password of that file.

I managed to make that file password protected but unfortunately I was not able to access that file through my application. Actually i not getting where to set the user name and password to open that file. Entering username and password in connection string is not working.

**EDIT**
Sorry for bit confusion

I want that file to be password protected rather than database connection.
That file should not be opened in any case. For that i managed to set password on file using ms access itself but i m not able to open that file through my application.

**Edit2: "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Projects\GargTubes\dbGargTubes.mdb; User Id=""; Password="abc";"**

I am using **MS-Access 03**

**Edit 3:**

> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
> Source=E:\Projects\GargTubes\dbGargTubes.mdb;
> Database Password=abc;"
>
> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
> Source=E:\Projects\GargTubes\dbGargTubes.mdb;JET
> OLEDB: Database Password=abc;
>
> Error: Could not find installable ISAM

Comment: Database passwords are very flimsy.

Comment: Can you clarify *how* you locked down the database? There seem to be at least two options for that.

Comment: Did you use Access Security or a Database Password?

Comment: @Remou  I dont know the exact word but i think it would be a access security

Comment: @Shantanu: Can you show us the connection string that you are currently using (and which is not working)? Second question: When opening the DB in Access, do you have to enter user name and password or only a password?

Comment: @Heinzi: i have to enter only password

Comment: @Shantanu: Thanks, that clears things up. Now, can you try using `Jet OLEDB:Database Password` instead of `Password` as described in Pbirkoff's or my answer?

Comment: In that case, see the first reply or http://www.connectionstrings.com/access : Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;

Comment: And I repeat, database passwords are very flimsy.

Comment: @Shantanu: Use the connection string *exactly as specified*. Don't leave away the `Jet OLEDB:` part. This causes the ISAM error you are experiencing.

Comment: @Shantanu: *Exactly* means *exactly*. ;-) Don't add a space between `Jet OLEDB:` and `Database Password`.

Comment: @Heinzi : Thx It worked. I didn't expected that this could have created a problem.

Comment: @Remou: "database passwords are very flimsy". This was certainly correct in Jet 4 (which is the Jet version in question here), but the ACE and Access 2007 greatly enhance the encryption strength of database passwords. They are still completely useless, but they are no longer "flimsy."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about passing *user name* and password, I assume that you have protected your database by setting user rights rather than by using the "database password" option. In that case, users and groups are stored in `system.mdw`. Be sure to include the path to `system.mdw` in your connection string (`Jet OLEDB:System Database=path\to\system.mdw`, see [Connection strings for Access](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access) for samples).

Alternatively, you use the "database password" feature. Then, the `Jet OLEDB:Database Password` option described in the other answers should work. To spell it out:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Projects\GargTubes\dbGargTubes.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abc
```

Comment: This is for a secured database, not a password protected database.

Comment: @Remou: Then why does Shntanu talk about passing the "user name" in the connection string?

Comment: Shantanu distinctly says database password, so I suspect that user name and password is a misunderstanding in this case.

Comment: @Remou : I also want a secure database so that no one can open the file other than a developer itself. So i only want that file to be password protected. If user deletes that file that is not a problem but he cannot open that file in any case. As this application has to be run on pendrive.

Comment: Did you use a Database Password of Access Security?

Comment: @Remou: Thanks for the feedback. I've adapted my answer to emphasize that it only applies to the "secured database" case.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look into that connection strings samples: [Connection strings for Access](http://connectionstrings.com/access)

Comment: This is the correct answer, as far as I can see, and there is even a heading "With database password" in the link to make life easy.

Comment: Maybe link to http://connectionstrings.com/access instead? The file in question is a mdb database, not accdb.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the database password in your connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
```

Comment: As the poster states, "Entering username and password in connection string is not working"

Comment: +1, since, as it turns out, this might happen to be the correct answer. (The author specified the password in the wrong way.)

Comment: In the original unedited post, he didn't show how he was specifying it at all. Nice to see more detail in the edits now :-)